# How to pass a multiple elements of the list to a re.split() function ?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
f = open('sentences.txt')
lines = [line.lower() for line in f]
print lines[0:5]
words = re.split("\s+", lines[0:5])
```

with "print" it works perfectly well, but when I try to do the same inside of re.split(), I get an error "TypeError: expected string or buffer"

Comment: Perhaps instead of passing five strings into `split`, you could call `split` five times with five individual strings.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Sounds a little bit like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
words = re.split("\s+", ''.join(lines))
```

The split function expects a string, which is then split into substrings based on the regex and returned as a list. Passing a list would not make a whole lot of sense. If you're expecting it to take your list of strings and split each string element individually and then return a list of lists of strings, you'll have to do that yourself:

```
lines_split = []
for line in lines:
    lines_split.append(re.split("\s+", line))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join), i.e.:

```
words = "".join(lines[0:5]).split()
```

---

Note:
No need for `re` module,  `split()` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, you are getting a `TypeError` in your function call, which means that you are passing the wrong parameter from what the function is expecting. So you need to think about what you are passing.

If you have a debugger or IDE you can step through and see what type your parameter has, or even use `type` to print it, via

```
print(type(lines[0:5]))
```

which returns

```
<class 'list'>
```

so you need to transform that into a String. Each element in your list is a String, so think of a way to get each row out of the list. An example would be

```
words = [re.split('\s+', line) for line in lines]
```

where I am using a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to step through `lines` and process each row individually.

Answer (score 0):

Your `re.split('\s+', line)` is the equivalent of `line.split()` so you can write

```
words = [line.split() for line in lines]
```

See the [documentation for `str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).